# How to migrate websites from .NET 2 to .NET 4 using Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, migration

Hi I would like to know the correct steps and procedure required to convert existing .NET 2 websites to .NET4 using Visual Studio. Please let me know if there is any online resources (blog,tutorial,video,official doc) available that teaching you. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio to open a Web project that was developed for the .NET Framework 2.0, the .NET Framework 3.0, or the .NET Framework 3.5, Visual Studio can automatically perform all the changes to Web.config files that are required to be able to run using .NET Framework version 4.

If the project is a local IIS project and you are using IIS 7.0, Visual Studio can also reassign the application to an application pool that is associated with the .NET Framework version 4.

For step by step instructions, see link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483478(v=vs.100).aspx